# Fitting an exponential model: Mathematica vs. Excel

Tags: fitting, excel

My data is:

```
data = {{0, 0.05}, {40, 0.079}, {80, 0.113}, {120, 0.18}, {160, 0.31}, {200, 0.5}, {240, 0.71}, {280,0.86}, {320, 1.02}};
```

With Excel we can fit the data with $0.0548996\,e^{0.0099675\,x}$ which is more or less good: (blue curve is the fit)

[image]

Now, if we try with Mathematica:

```
FindFit[data, a*E^(b x), {a, b}, x]
```

returns: `Working precision MachinePrecision is insufficient to achieve the requested accuracy or precision; {a -> 2.76357*10^-76, b -> 1.}`, which is obviously wrong.

How can one find the best fit with Mathematica for this data?

Comment: Give it some starting values, for instance: FindFit[data, a*E^(b x), {{a, 0}, {b, 0}}, x]

Comment: You fit a different model with Excel.  You fit `y = log(a) + b*x  + error` with Excel and your *Mathematica* model is `y = a*Exp[b*x] + error`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You fit a different model with Excel than what you fit with *Mathematica* which is why the coefficient estimates do not match.  To get the coefficient estimates you present from Excel, the equivalent *Mathematica* code is

```
dataLog = data;
dataLog[[All, 2]] = Log[dataLog[[All, 2]]];
nlmLog = NonlinearModelFit[dataLog, Log[a] + b x, {{a, 0.05}, {b, 0}}, x];
nlmLog["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 0.0548996, b -> 0.0099675} *)
```

When the same model is fit you get an exact match between Excel and *Mathematica*.

And unless there's some theoretical reason for the basic form of the model, both models don't appear to be adequate.

Comment: Adding a squared term (i.e., Log[y] = Log[a] + b*x + c*x^2 + error) does lower the $AIC_c$ value by 1 unit.  So you might consider that.  Again, if there's some theoretical model, that should be considered along with if there is any issue for predictions near 1 being more important to be correct than predictions near 0.

Answer (score 9):

A logistic fit looks much better than your exponential:

```
data = {{0, 0.05}, {40, 0.079}, {80, 0.113}, {120, 0.18},
        {160, 0.31}, {200, 0.5}, {240, 0.71}, {280, 0.86}, {320, 1.02}};

F = NonlinearModelFit[data,
                      A/(1 + E^(-(t-t0)/b)),
                      {{A, 1.2}, {t0, 200}, {b, 60}},
                      t];
F["ParameterTable"]
```

$$
\begin{array}{l|llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{t-Statistic} & \text{P-Value}
   \\
\hline
 A & 1.2435 & 0.054107 & 22.9823 & \text{4.4469648388679$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7} \\
 \text{t0} & 225.796 & 6.97604 & 32.3674 & \text{5.782867042247399$\grave{
   }$*${}^{\wedge}$-8} \\
 b & 62.76 & 3.34381 & 18.769 & \text{1.4770509264242727$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6} \\
\end{array}
$$

```
Plot[F[t], {t, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, Point[data]}]
```

[image]

The fit could be improved further if your data included error estimates.

Comment: A much better fit!  But I want to quibble about the statement "improved further if your data included error estimates."  If the errors are all equal, then the estimates, standard errors, and P-values (hence the fit) are identical to those with no error estimates.  If the error estimates vary (and are more or less correct), then one will get a more "appropriate" fit as opposed to an "improved" fit.  (And *Mathematica* has yet to implement "mixed models" (directly) which would be an even more appropriate model.)

Comment: @JimB your quibble is much appreciated and maybe I didn’t use the right terminology. My feeling is that this dataset is close to exponential on the left and therefore from physical considerations should have inhomogeneous error estimates that describe the special nature of the zero-line (i.e. error bars need to get smaller as the measurements approach zero because of some positivity constraint). Yet the fit I present does not fit this left tail very well, and on a LogPlot looks quite bad. These intuitions can only be solidified with error bars and remain guesswork without these.

Comment: I think we're in complete agreement: fitting takes more than just the data points.  Fitting also includes subject matter knowledge if there is some expected functional form and knowledge of measurement error (error estimates).  There's also the lack-of-fit error over and above the measurement error but *Mathematica" does not offer a high-level mixed model (i.e., multiple sources of error) function.  Something like PROC MIXED or PROC NLMIXED from SAS or the lme4 package in R really needs to be added.